# How to do AJAX in Django CMS Admin

Tags: ajax, django, django-admin

I have 2 models in Django CMS - a Map (which has name and an image attributes), and a Location, which one of it's attributes is a Map. I want, when the user changes the Map, to perform an AJAX request to get the map details for that item so that I can add the Map image to the page to do some further jQuery processing with it. But I'm new to Django and I can't seem to figure it out. Anything I find seems unrelated - in that it talks about using AJAX on front end forms.

I have my jQuery file ready to go but I don't know what to put for the URL of the AJAX call and how/where to set up the endpoint in Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seem related to custom Django admin url.
First, update your MapAdmin to provide an endpoint to search location

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import JsonResponse

class MapAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        admin_view = self.admin_site.admin_view
        info = self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.model_name
        urls = [
            url(r'^search_location$', admin_view(self.search_location), name=("%s_%s_search_location" % (info))),
        ]
        return urls + super(VideoAdmin, self).get_urls()

    def search_location(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        map = request.GET.get('map')
        # Do something with map param to get location.
        # Set safe=False if location_data is an array.
        return JsonResponse(["""..location_data"""], safe=False)
```

Next, somewhere in your template file, define the URL point to search location endpoint. And use that URL to fetch location data
once map is changed.

```
var searchLocationUrl = "{% url 'admin:appName_mapModel_search_location' %}";
```

Comment: I guess I'm confused because I don't have a template file. I'm only working in the admin. I have my .js file where I'm making the ajax call. How can I get that ajax URL in my .js file? Also I don't understand the info variable and why it's necessary for the URL?

Comment: `info`, is a prefix to make the name of URL be clear, example your app is `CMS` and your model is `Map`, the url name becomes `admin:cms_map_search_location`, I don't like hard assign string so I used `info` instead.

I'm not sure the admin url prefix in your project but I guess the ajax URL that you mentioned is:
`/admin/cms/map/search_location`

Comment: Thank you, I was able to figure out the right URL eventually. and obtain and return my map object with map_object = serializers.serialize('json', Map.objects.filter(id=map_id))